# unable to replicate data from couchdb docker image to localhost couchdb. but replication is completed from localhost couchdb to docker image

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, ubuntu-20.04, wsl-2, couchdb-3.x

I am currently working on a hyper ledger fabric. fabric use CouchDB docker image to store data. I want to store that CouchDB data into my local host CouchDB. At that time I am facing this issue. I am working from wsl2 with the ubuntu subsystem. the host is windows 10.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide more details about your setup and what you have tried, along with any relevant errors or logs

Comment: Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far.